# Testing differences between SqlDecimal and C# Decimal

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion, decimal

I'm trying to validate that a decimal in c# will fit into a db column decimal. The SqlDecimal object allows you to pass in a precision and scale as well as the decimal bits to the constructor. I know the size of the column and so before we write the data I check each input so I can produce business required output.

In this case we are storing a percent, so the precision is **13** and the scale is **10**. I have a testing harness that I've condensed below into a unti test for SO. This sample is throwing an Arithmetic Overflow error on the SqlDecimal constructor line:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDecimalFits()
    {
        decimal d = 10.3m;
        SqlDecimal sqlDecimal = new SqlDecimal(13, 10, d >= 0, Decimal.GetBits(d));
        Assert.AreEqual(d, sqlDecimal.Value);
    }
```

Does anyone know why this blows up?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `SqlDecimal` constructor with the decimal type directly. Like this  `SqlDecimal sqlDecimal = new SqlDecimal(d);`.

Comment: I can, but then it doesn't validate the trailing zero problem I mentioned, below in a comment. This throws an error and will work: SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(new SqlDecimal(value), precision, scale);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of `Decimal.GetBits` is not compatible with the `SqlDecimal`'s constructor parameter.

`Decimal.GetBits` returns an array that represents the exact structure of the decimal, which includes the 96-bit scaled integer value and 8 bits for the exponent (plus 1 sign bit and 27 unused bits).

The [`SqlDecimal` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4atwkb98(v=vs.110).aspx) that you are using takes an `int` array that represents "The 128-bit unsigned integer that provides the value of the new SqlDecimal." - NOT the *represenatation* of that decimal value.  The `scale` parameter determines what the *actual* value of the decimal will be.

So you are effectively passing in a different value than the constructor expects.  The .NET decimal equivalent of 10.3m is

```
0000000001100111-0000000000000000-0000000000000000-10000000000000000
```

Where `1100111` is the binary equivalent of 103, and `1` is the scale.

The integer equivalent of that binary value is more than 13 digits long, which is why you get an overflow when passing it to the SqlDecimal constructor.

I would not play around with bit-fiddling and instead just use the raw `decimal` value, letting SQL convert it to the right precision and scale automatically.

> I'm trying to validate that a decimal in c# will fit into a db column decimal.

Well, the largest value that will fit into a `DECIMAL(13,10)` is `999.9999999999`, which is well below the maximum value of a `decimal`. So no, you can't store *any* C# decimal value in a `DECIMAL(13,10)` SQL column.

(technically I think you can store `9999999999999` by dropping the precision, but even that is well below the maximum value of a `decimal`).

Comment: SqlDecimal's constructor takes in an int array, not a byte array, but this likely is the reason. The problem with just passing a decmial in is that the trailing zeros on the decimal c# decimal are flexible, where as in sql server they are always padded, leading to overflow issues on the output.

Comment: Ah, ok, so not messing with the bits myself does work, I just have to set the precision and scale after. Thank you! SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(new SqlDecimal(value), precision, scale);

Comment: Yes that would work, however you should not need to create a `SqlDecimal` directly.  The SQL provider should implicitly convert your `decimal` value for you.  If you have a case where you _need_ to create a `SqlDecimal` then that should work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `Decimal.GetBits(d)` is overflowing the Int32 return type.
Try doing just `Int32 bits = Decimal.GetBits(d)` and see if it throws the same error.

Comment: `Decimal.GetBits` returns an `int[]`, not an `Int32`

Comment: Worth a shot, breaking that out into its own line still resulted in an exception being thrown from the SqlDecimal constructor.