# validating decimal format in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a decimal values in a flat file ,and I want to validate that the decimal values is `decimal(18,2)`.

I am already storing the file content in a variable and can echo the column.

My code is:

```
$EntryList=Import-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Header @(
      "RECORD_TYPE", 
      "COD_FIN_INSTRUMENT_ATTRIBUTE",
      "COD_SEGM_REG",
        "IMP_CCF_RWA") -Path $datarecordnum
```

Comment: Where is this decimal value you're seeking?  Are you validating format or content?

Comment: I am validating format

Comment: You should clarify what you're looking for.  There's no clue given on what the data looks like or what you want.

Comment: ok ,let me get you a sample of data and reply back to you

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to verify that a given number can be represented by SQL Server's `DECIMAL(18,2)` format.

I would try converting the value to C#'s `SqlDecimal` data type, which is intended to represent SQL Server's `DECIMAL` data type.  Then try to force the value into a given scale and precision, and verify that the value matches the original value.

Here's a sample function:

```
function Test-DecimalFormat {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
         $Value,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [int]
        $Precision,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [int]
        $Scale
    )

    try {
        $DecimalValue = [System.Convert]::ToDecimal($Value);
        $SqlDecimalValue = [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal]::new($DecimalValue);
        return ([System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal]::ConvertToPrecScale($SqlDecimalValue, $Precision, $Scale).Value -eq $DecimalValue);
    }
    catch {
        return $false;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
PS C:\> Test-DecimalFormat -Value 123456789123456789.78 -Precision 18 -Scale 2
False
PS C:\> Test-DecimalFormat -Value 789.78 -Precision 18 -Scale 2
True
PS C:\> Test-DecimalFormat -Value 789.78901 -Precision 18 -Scale 2
False
PS C:\> Test-DecimalFormat -Value ([decimal]::MaxValue) -Precision 18 -Scale 2
False
PS C:\> Test-DecimalFormat -Value ([decimal]::MaxValue) -Precision 38 -Scale 0
True
```

---

Note that this function isn't perfect for very large precisions, since the `NUMERIC()` SQL data type has a maximum value of 10^38 - 1, while `System.Decimal` caps out at 2^96.  If you need exact values outside the range of `System.Decimal`, you're probably going to have to compare the binary representations of the values.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897221/696808) for more.

Comment: Test-DecimalFormat -Value '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999' -Precision 38 -Scale 0  bug....

Comment: @Esperento57 Sure, fixed.